# Can not write data to file in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file, nsfilemanager

I manually created a file `amutha.txt` in the documents folder. I tried to write data to that file. code which I used is

```
let string="Amuthapriya"
try string.write(to:fileName, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

This is executed correctly means having no exceptions or errors. But then When I open amutha.txt the file is empty. Why the string is not written in that file? What Mistake I am doing?
My code is:

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

@objc func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton) {
    print(sender.titleLabel?.text)
    let documentUrl:URL = getDocumentsDirectory()
    let fileName=documentUrl.appendingPathComponent("priya.txt", isDirectory: false)
    let filePath=fileName.path
    print( FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath))
    do {
        let string="Amuthapriya"
        try string.write(to:fileName, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("written successfully")
        print("filePath: \(filePath)") 
    } catch {

    }
}
```

Comment: Check file at path which is displayed in console

Comment: use your catch block to print the error . Inside catch, do `print(error.localizedDescription)` and update here

Comment: @KishanBhatiya You are correct. I checked the path which displayed in console.There is a file with given data.Thank You So Much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to print path of your file in console because you are watching wrong file and check that file if it is available there or not and check content

```
do {
        let string="Amuthapriya"
        try string.write(to:fileName, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("written successfully")
        print("filePath: \(filePath)")  // check file here
    } catch {

    }
```

Comment: How is this different from the code in the question?

Comment: @Matt please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979873/file-does-not-exist-in-ios-swift

Answer (score 0):

> I manually created a file *amutha.txt* in the documents folder.  But then When I open *amutha.txt* the file is empty.

But the text is being written to *priya.txt*.

```
let fileName=documentUrl.appendingPathComponent("priya.txt", isDirectory: false)
```

So you are looking in the wrong file.

(Also do not change from file URL to file path string. Use file URL only.)